# Incremental build on iOS is not working

Tags: ios, visual-studio-cordova

Using VS2015 RTM together with remotebuild@1.0.1, I have the problem that the incremental build is not working. The problem is that the changed web resources are not updated in the remote-builds directory on the Mac.

I assume the problem is that the uploaded upload_xxxx.tgz contains an empty www folder. Currently, I know 2 workarounds:

- stop and restart the remotebuild
- rebuild in Visual Studio

Both alternatives I do not like. They are easy to forget, and they take a lot of time.

Is there a solution to the problem - or a better workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until the product team fixes the bug, you can patch a nodejs file as follows:

1. Open File Explorer and Navigate to %APPDATA%\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\lib\
2. Replace file remoteBuild.js with one from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/master/known-issues/ios-remote-incremental-build-fix/remoteBuild.js)

*Note: if you are not using default npm installation location, then to find out the directory where remoteBuild.js is located, run “npm config get prefix” (from a command prompt) to get the base of the directory, “C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm” for me, and then replace “\node_modules\vs-tac\lib\remoteBuild.js”.*

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not fix my problem: I replaced the remoteBuild.js file with the downloaded version and restarted Visual Studio. But still the incremental build creates an upload_xxxx.tgz with an empty www folder.
I also checked in ProcMon. The new remoteBuild.js is used.

Comment: The new version fixes the problem if I change a static file in my www folder. But I am using appBundle.js generated by Grunt. And there the problem still exists. But probably here is the case slightly different. Therefore I marked this question as answered an created a [new question for the appBundle stuff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243779/incremental-build-ignores-appbundle-js-when-it-is-generated-via-grunt). @ali

Answer (score 0):

So I think the iosRemoteLaunch.js also needs to be updated, to reflect the new method name of httpOptions vs httpOptionsAsync. If you dont, you end up getting this little gem:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at invokeUrl (C:\Users\Nigel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\lib\iosRemoteLaunch.js:31:24)
at Object.remote.debug (C:\Users\Nigel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\lib\iosRemoteLaunch.js:57:12)
at C:\Users\Nigel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\emulator.js:37:27
at _fulfilled (C:\Users\Nigel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\Nigel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Nigel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
at C:\Users\Nigel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\q\q.js:557:44
at flush (C:\Users\Nigel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
```